# How do I list sandboxes associated to my production org using sfdx-cli?

Tags: salesforcedx, sandbox

I would like to list all the sandboxes associated with my production org.

What I want to view via cli, is what I see here - Setup>Sandboxes

Version being used is sfdx-cli 7.179.0

Comment: Hi Indu, just to clarify, are you looking to see what sandboxes you have authenticated via the SFDX CLI or are you wanting to understand what sandboxes are associated to your Production instance?

Comment: I want to list the sandboxes associated to my Production Instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tooling query with the DX CLI and then query for `SandboxInfo`

`sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT Id, SandboxName, Description, LicenseType, HistoryDays FROM SandboxInfo" --usetoolingapi`

Comment: Thanks Christian. I had to provide user parameter -u as well. And I got the results :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the CLI can list what orgs you've created or authenticated yourself, rather than what orgs are available in Production. The best way to view this information is to log into your org and check Sandboxes in Setup.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve using force:mdapi:listmetadata? How about running an SOQL query force:data:soql:query?